# kubectl port-forward: error upgrading connection

Tags: macos, kubernetes, portforwarding, kubectl

I am trying to port forward my machine to a remote rpc machine in kubernetes using "kubectl port-forward [pod name] 5001:5001" and am getting "error upgrading connection". Has anyone else had this issue? I have tried restarting mDNSResponder and using different ports.

Comment: Is "error upgrading connection" the only response? Any more detail?

Comment: The code shows that there should be more to the message. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/4bba6105657a8b7a46adf67140cb4065fff1885e/staging/src/k8s.io/client-go/tools/portforward/portforward.go#L137

Comment: facing the same issue: using k9s and facing error while doing port forward